# How can I create a floating grid using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How would one create a layout as in the image below: [image]

Is it possible only with the float attribute where we have four divs? I have roughly the following code and 3 is pushed down by 2 (Browsers IE8+).

```
#one #three {
    float: left;
}

#two, #four {
    float: right;
}

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

Note: height(1) + height(3) != height(2)

Comment: Post relative code please.

Comment: @henser I have edited but IE8+

Comment: Well ... forget calc() and flexbox then ... gotta stick with float or with the less recommendable table grid

Comment: Changing the source order would be the way to make this flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this code structure answers your needs ... [jsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yg3dyq7b/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="col_1">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
</div>
<div class="col_2">
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col_1{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
}

.col_2{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
}

#one{
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    background:yellow;
}

#two{
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
}

#three{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}

#four{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:purple;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a floating grid solution but seems like that it is not possible it should support IE8 (without javascript) so I have to restructure as you have done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pvashishat/49chp8ny/

use HTML

`<div id="xxx">
    <div class="left_wrap">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_wrap">
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="four"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

CSS

```
.left_wrap {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.right_wrap {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.one, .three {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 40px;
}

.two, .four {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 80px;
}

#xxx {
    display:inline-block;
}
```